# logging in to instagram with mechanize python

Tags: python, authentication, mechanize

I have been trying to login to my instagram account with mechanize python for the past while and for some reason it is not working.

To check if I have logged in correctly, I decided to check the url with "br.geturl()", which should read "https://www.instagram.com/" once the login is successful, but after I run the program it is just:
"https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/username=username_here&password=password_here"

Anyone know how to fix this?

Note: I know forsure my login info is correct.

Here is my code:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
url = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/"
br.set_handle_robots(False)
response = br.open(url)

f = list(br.forms())

br.form = f[0]
print br.form


br.form["username"] = 'username_goes_here'
br.form["password"] = 'password_goes_here'

br.submit()

print br.geturl()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the form is generated via JavaScript. So it could not be found on the html. One of the way would be using Selenium Webdriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Usr/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher")
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="username"]')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="password"]')
login_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="oF4XW sqdOP  L3NKy      "]')

username.send_keys("username")
password.send_keys("password")

#test to see if input values are reflecting
print(username.get_attribute('value'))
print(password.get_attribute('value'))

#login
login_btn.click()
logged_in_class = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("logged-in")
not_logged_in_class = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("not-logged-in")

#to check if logged-in or not-logged-in
print(len(logged_in_class))
print(len(not_logged_in_class))


driver.quit()
```